# Looking for Windows plotting software to read data from UDP packets

Tags: networking, data-visualization, real-time

We are working on a project that streams multiple channels of ADC information to a Windows PC.  Each packet has a payload of 768 samples acquired over about 4ms.

Final implementation of this project will be sending the data to a collection computer via UDP packets over Ethernet.

We are currently using a serial port connection from the PIC to the Windows computer for testing purposes. PIC Serial port is configured for 900k bits/second and we are using a FTDI high-speed serial -> USB converter to get the data into the PC.

The reason for using the serial port is that there is a very nice serial plotting software package available.  [Windows Serial Plotter](https://hackaday.io/project/5334-serialplot-realtime-plotting-software) displays multiple plots in real time.  The problem is that we are missing a whole lot of samples between successive packets because the time required to send those 768 bytes of data is almost 15ms.

This serial port connection is for development purposes only - data transport in the final version will be via Ethernet.

What we are looking for is a software package running under Windows that has similar functionality to the SerialPlot program but that accepts input data from a UDP stream.  I'm hoping that someone can tell us if something like this exists.

I debated posting this question here because it doesn't fall under the direct guidelines for this site.  However, this is a tool that facilitates the design of our project and may also be helpful to others who are sending data via Ethernet.

Comment: I recall writing such a software in C#. And it took under 1-2 hours of work.

Comment: Matlab? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/291708-real-time-data-graphing-921600-baud-udp

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 It doesn't look like the sample code requires any special packages, so [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) might work as a free alternative to Matlab.

Comment: Meguno link https://www.megunolink.com/articles/arduino-ethernet-communication-via-udp/

Comment: python/matplotlib or python/pyqtgraph will also do this quite easily

Comment: easy for you to say....;)

Comment: If you can afford to invest a little time, the python/numpy/scipy/matplotlib path will give you the best, most flexible, and future-proof solution. Also free. I've been solving similar problems for the last 15 years with this set of tools and I get to keep stealing code from my last project. And the tools keep getting better too.

Comment: If you implement something yourselves just don't try updating the image/plot every frame - 4 milliseconds = 250 Hz most monitors do not display over 75 Hz (and many are 50 or 60 Hz) and the human eye sees that as stable so one thread or process capturing the data and another updating the display at a much lower rate would be the way to go.